# Get ComboBox current text in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, postback, viewstate

I would like to get the selecteditem from a combobox in the page load, before the postback happens, is this possible?

Based on the selecteditem value I am executing different code in the Page Load, so I really need the value before the postback (in the page_load).

For example:

1. In the page load I am comparing the selecteditem with a string, if that is equal `(selectedItem.ToString() == "Test")`
2. Then I would like to add attributes to a textbox, like `textBox1.Attributes.Add("hello", "world")`.

And since the Page_Load executes before a PostBack, I have no clue how to get the selecteditem in the page_load so I can use it in my example above.

Comment: page load is called in every post back

Comment: Are you tracking `if (!IsPostBack){}` in page_load?

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this in **page_load** if you want to only check on page load but not on popstback:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{

    if(combo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Test")
    {

     // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a value of combobox before Page_Load because control is not render before Page_Load even also not in Pre_Init event. It will render after Page_Load.

You can access value after Page_Load Event.